# Shorter version of \mintinline{language}

Tags: minted

I'm using `minted` and for each inline code, I have to use `\mintinline{python}{}` which is quite long to type or copy for the whole big book.

Is there any way to rewrite this command into something like `shcode{}`?

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}   
\usepackage{minted}
\newminted{py}{bgcolor=gray!5, breakline = true}
\begin{document}
Inline code goes here: \mintinline{python}{tuple()}
% Can we make it as \shcode{tuple()}
\end{document}
```

Please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like you use `\newminted` to define new minted environment, you can use `\newmintinline` to define a new inline macro:

```
% !TeX program = txs:///arara
% arara: pdflatex: {synctex: on, interaction: nonstopmode, shell: yes}
\documentclass{article}   
\usepackage{minted}
\newminted{py}{bgcolor=gray!5, breakline = true}

\newmintinline[shcode]{python}{}
\begin{document}
Inline code goes here: \mintinline{python}{tuple()}
 Can we make it as \shcode{tuple()}
\end{document}
```